# Portal de Consulta ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Trabalho em uma empresa prestadora de serviços. Na empresa temos centenas de bancos de dados Oracle e SQL-Server de todos os clientes. Esses bancos contém informações dos itens patrimoniais existentes naquela empresa além de outras informações comerciais e financeiras. A medida que o trabalho vai sendo executado os funcionários por meio do sistema interno alimenta as várias tabelas, tais como: etapas do projeto, históricos das execuções, emissão de notas fiscais, boletos, cronogramas, etc. 
    Nossa meta é criar uma área na internet onde o cliente possa logar-se e consultar as informações para ele disponibilizadas.

Imagino uma tabela com usuário e senha onde o sistema valida e verifica à quais bases de quais servidores ele tem acesso. 
     Caso ele tenha acesso à uma unica base o sistema já se conecta aquela base e ele passa a consultar sua informações relativas a execução de seu trabalho. Se houver mais de uma base o sistema solicita qual base ele quer acessar e segue igualmente.

Como usei recentemente o ASP.NET MVC 4 para construir um aplicativo com o RAZOR e achei bastante produtivo lhes pergunto, consigo desenvolver esse novo projeto usando ASP.NET MVC 4? Seria legal porque o cliente poderia acessar 
essas informações, inclusive, do celular.

Eu não consigo imaginar como seria o modelo. Pois, em tese, eu teria apenas uma tabela como porta de entrada e depois o sistema se conecta a uma outra base qualquer e eu passo a fazer select lá. Posso criar o modelo baseado em uma
base de dados e alternar a conexão de lá pra cá a vontade?

Ou deveria replicar as colunas que serão consultadas em outras tabelas no mesmo banco que esta a tabela de login e através de trigger nos bancos originais alimentas-las?

Conhece algum link que me daria uma boa noção de como fazer isso?

Se ficou confuso, estou a disposição para maiores informações.

Grato.

Comment: Parabéns pela pergunta. Achei excelente.

Comment: Você diz "centenas" de base de dados, mas essas bases ficam no mesmo servidor? Server/User/Password são os mesmos e o que muda é a base, ou cada base pode estar em um servidor diferente?

Comment: Participando do escopo as bases do Oracle estão em um servidor e as do SQL-Server em outro. Existe sim,  um usuário e senha com a qual posso ter acesso a qualquer uma dessas bases, além das utilizadas pelos colaboradores que variam de base para base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Como usei recentemente o ASP.NET MVC 4 para construir um aplicativo com o RAZOR e achei bastante produtivo lhes pergunto consigo desenvolver esse novo projeto usando ASP.NET MVC 4?

Em resumo, sim.

> Eu não consigo imaginar como seria o modelo. Pois, em tese, eu teria apenas uma tabela como porta de entrada e depois o sistema se conecta a uma outra base qualquer e eu passo a fazer select lá. Posso criar o modelo baseado em uma base de dados e alternar a conexão de lá pra cá a vontade?

Primeiro vamos desmistificar isso de "usar a conexão em outro lugar". Num sistema ASP.NET MVC, você pode abrir quantas conexões quiser.

Se você for usar ASP.NET MVC4 (o que não é muito recomendado porque o MVC4 já é um padrão antigo), você pode criar um projeto com Entity Framework e definir no contexto criado pela aplicação seus usuários e seus respectivos níveis de permissão. Isto é feito utilizando o Membership. Posso linkar nesta resposta alguns artigos que podem ser úteis para esta implementação, mas já aviso que isto pode dar algum trabalho.

Já no ASP.NET MVC5, criando o projeto com o Entity Framework e Individual User Accounts, você terá à disposição um mecanismo praticamente pronto de autenticação dos seus usuários, através do ASP.NET Identity. Será necessária alguma alfaiataria, mas nada muito complicado. Também posso colocar alguns artigos que podem ser do seu interesse.

Agora, o mais importante: suas bases legadas. Você pode mapeá-las usando o Entity Framework ou utilizar outros mecanismos de abertura de conexão com a sua base, como ADO.NET + Repositório Genérico ou ainda Dapper. Para cada tabela das suas bases legadas, o correto é criar uma classe (que neste contexto chamamos de Model) com propriedades, sendo cada propriedade uma coluna da sua tabela. Feito isso, cada seleção de dados feita na tabela deverá preencher um objeto da classe por linha encontrada. Apenas para não alongar muito a pergunta, posso colocar exemplos de como fazer isso mais tarde, ou em outras perguntas.

Acredito que suas bases de dados nos seus clientes devam seguir um padrão de tabelas, e por isto este mapeamento é viável. Já para decidir em qual base se conectar, você pode criar um esquema entre usuários e empresas, e para cada empresa um outro esquema de quais bases de dados são usadas por cada empresa. Assim você pode montar *connection strings* dinamicamente e inicializar suas conexões ou contextos de dados de acordo com a requisição feita.

Este conceito é chamado de **multitenência**.

> Ou deveria replicar as colunas que serão consultas em outras tabelas no mesmo banco que esta a tabela de login e através de trigger nos bancos originais alimentas-las?

Por experiência, isto não fica bom, sobretudo se as tecnologias forem de bancos diferentes. Melhor construir uma aplicação que leia todas as bases.

> Conhece algum link que me daria uma boa noção de como fazer isso?

Este site de Q&A é uma boa base de conhecimentos. Vou direciona-lo para os tópicos que comentei acima.

- [ASP.NET Membership](http://www.devmedia.com.br/seguranca-em-aplicacoes-net-utilizando-o-provider-asp-net-membership/27822), [perguntas do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=membership);
- [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity), [perguntas do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+identity);
- [Repositório Genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+reposit%C3%B3rio+gen%C3%A9rico);
- [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/), [perguntas do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework);
- [Dapper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dapper).

Comment: Ótimo, valeu pela resposta. Tenho tudo do que preciso por enquanto. Abs. :)